# Jqplot situation with the last bar in the graph

Tags: javascript, graph, jqplot

**Situation**

I'm trying to have some space over the last `xaxis` options.

For example:

```
xaxis. min:-max:6
```

- Only half of the last bar is shown, and if I try to use `tickOption`, it doesn't appear because it is outside of the canvas.

**code**:
http://jsfiddle.net/chalien/zEQe7/

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Your array isn't set right for the bar chart. You don't need to tell the plot rendered it is point number 1, 2, 3, etc... It knows it by himself.

Just change the array definition to:

```
 [[4, 6, 2, 5, 6]]
```

And your graph will be rendered correctly, with or without the `min` and `max` definitions.

**Here is the full code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.jqplot('chart2',  [[4, 6, 2, 5, 6]],
{ title:'Exponential Line',
      seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                varyBarColor: true  
            }
        },
   axes: {
            xaxis: {  
               max:6,
               min:0,
                renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer
            }
        }
});

 </script>
```